# What module/plugin does TechCrunch use for this sharing buttons?

Tags: sharing, social-media

I've seen the social sharing buttons like the ones found on TechCrunch on other sites. Is this  a module/plugin like meebo or AddToAny? If so what is it called?

[image: Sharing Buttons]

Thanks,
Greg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They use AddThis http://www.addthis.com